# Oracle sql query closest date for day of year

Tags: oracle, date

I am looking for a simpler solution to find the nearest date (with respect to sysdate) for a given day of year value. Examples (in format "dd/mm/yyyy")

```
sysdate = "01/01/2012" input = 365     result = "31/12/2011"  
sysdate = "01/01/2012" input = 366     result = "31/12/2012"
sysdate = "01/01/2012" input =   1     result = "01/01/2012"
sysdate = "31/12/2012" input =   1     result = "01/01/2013"
```

Basically the resulting date can be in current year, previous year or next year. Initially I wrote a small procedure as given below. Here I am using a reference date instead of sysdate to test the results. This works for cases where the input day of year is not 366. But when it is 366, this fails and one may need to travel further backwards and forward to find the nearest valid date. After adding the checks for leap year (all conditions 4,100,400 etc) the code became a real mess.

I would appreciate if you can suggest a simpler, better and foolproof solution (function or single query). Please do not use complex constructs too specific to Oracle as I will have to port the same to DB2 as well. Also, efficiency is of least concern as it is not going to be executed heavily.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(ref_date_str varchar2, doy number) IS  
    ref_date         date ;  
    nearest_date     date ;  
BEGIN  
    ref_date := to_date(ref_date_str, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ;  

    WITH choices AS  
    (  
        SELECT trunc(ref_date, 'yyyy') + doy - 1 AS choice_date FROM dual  
        UNION  
        SELECT trunc(trunc(ref_date, 'yyyy') - 1, 'yyyy') + doy - 1 AS choice_date FROM dual  
        UNION  
        SELECT add_months(trunc(ref_date, 'yyyy'), 12) + doy - 1 AS choice_date FROM dual  
    )  
    SELECT choice_date INTO nearest_date FROM choices WHERE abs(ref_date - choice_date) =  
        (SELECT min(abs(ref_date - choice_date)) FROM choices) AND rownum < 2 ;  

    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(nearest_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) ;  
END ;  
/
```

Logically the algorithm I am considering is

```
for each year backwards from current year
  if a valid date found for the doy, and it is <= sysdate
     first_date = this valid date
     exit loop

for each year forward from current year
  if a valid date found for the doy, and it is > sysdate
     second_date = this valid date
     exit loop

chosen_date = closest_to_sysdate_among(first_date, second_date)
```

EDIT 1 : Given below is the implementation of the algorithm I have given above (there is some redundancy in the code). I am still looking forward for alternatives or refinements to the solutions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetNearestDate(reference_date DATE, day_of_year NUMBER) RETURN DATE IS  
    valid_date_1    DATE ;  
    valid_date_2    DATE ;  
    iter_date       DATE ;  
BEGIN  
    iter_date := trunc(reference_date, 'yyyy') ;  

    WHILE TRUE  
    LOOP  
        valid_date_1 := iter_date + day_of_year - 1 ;  

        IF valid_date_1 < add_months(iter_date, 12) AND valid_date_1 <= reference_date THEN  
            EXIT ;  
        END IF ;  

        iter_date := trunc(iter_date - 1, 'yyyy') ;  
    END LOOP ;  

    iter_date := trunc(reference_date, 'yyyy') ;  

    WHILE TRUE  
    LOOP  
        valid_date_2 := iter_date + day_of_year - 1 ;  

        IF valid_date_2 < add_months(iter_date, 12) AND valid_date_2 > reference_date THEN  
            EXIT ;  
        END IF ;  

        iter_date := add_months(iter_date, 12) ;  
    END LOOP ;  

    IF abs(valid_date_1 - reference_date) <= abs(valid_date_2 - reference_date) THEN  
        RETURN valid_date_1 ;  
    END IF ;  

    RETURN valid_date_2 ;  
END ;  
/
```

EDIT 2 : The check "valid_date_? < add_months" is to ensure that this date is on the same (iterated) year itself (otherwise, a value of 366, for a non-leap year will return next year start day). Also, the associated comparison with reference date is to guard against cases like (reference = "30/01/2012", input = 365). Here the valid_date_1 should be "31/12/2011" and not "30/12/2012", as the first one is the closest date to the reference, with day of year value as 365.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but is the date you're looking for stored in a table or are you just looking for the nearest date?

Comment: Nice question. I think the catch is leap years. If you look for 366 around the year 2000, the nearest one might be 4 years away.

Comment: @Ben, unfortunately the date is note stored in the table. It contains modified_date, start_day, end_day (eg: 31/12/2012, 365, 1 in which case the expected conversion is 365 = 30/12/2012 and 1 = 01/01/2013. modified_date is near the day values, but can be before, in between or even after them (eg: 31/12/2012, 1, 1). Now I am faced with a problem to convert these days into actual date values. Though the gap between the days is guaranteed to be less than 365, thus not requiring a complex solution, I thought I will make the function foolproof enough to handle any generic situation.

Comment: Why is `sysdate = "01/01/2012" input =   1     result = "01/01/2012"
` and not `result = "01/02/2012"`?

Comment: @René, I think there is some confusion. The requirement is, for a reference date (say sysdate), find nearest date with day of year ('DDD' in sql). As such, any date can be given as reference, and a value between 1 and 366 as the day of year. For the given example, it is the same day itself (01/01/2012) which is nearest to the reference date, with day of year = 1. Sorry if my question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution that I am planning to use for the time being. I had to avoid WITH clause in order to make it work with DB2. Peterson's solution helped to think in this direction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetNearestDate(reference_date DATE, day_of_year NUMBER) RETURN DATE IS  
    nearest_date DATE ;  
BEGIN  
    SELECT valid_date INTO nearest_date  
    FROM  
    (  
        SELECT first_date + day_of_year - 1 AS valid_date  
        FROM  
        (  
            SELECT add_months(trunc(reference_date, 'YYYY'), (rownum-10) * 12) AS first_date  
            FROM all_objects  
            WHERE rownum <= 20  
        )  
        WHERE to_char(first_date, 'YYYY') = to_char(first_date + day_of_year - 1, 'YYYY')  
        ORDER BY abs(first_date + day_of_year - 1 - reference_date), first_date  
    )  
    WHERE rownum < 2 ;  

    RETURN nearest_date ;  

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN  
    RETURN nvl(reference_date, sysdate) ;  
END ;  
/
```

Answer (score 1):

So if efficiency is not an issue I would use a precomputed table with dates, similar to the following:

```
with dates as
(SELECT to_date('01-01-1980', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + rownum day,
     to_number(to_char(to_date('01-01-1980', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + rownum,
                       'DDD')) day_of_year
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 100 * 365)
 select t.*
 from (select dates.*,
           abs(to_date('01-01-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - dates.day) diff
      from dates
     where dates.day_of_year = 1
     order by 3) t
 where rownum <= 1
```

So we have all the dates for ~100 years after 1980 and for each date we note which day in that year it was. After that we calculate the distance to all of the dates which are e.g. 1st in the year sort them ascending and the final result will be the first row.

The inner query is a bit specific to ORACLE, but I believe there should be a principle of generating (consecutive) rows in DB2 as well

Comment: Thanks Peterson. It is a bit of brute force (not your fault though). It definitely opens up a possibility to combine with my logic to ease up the execution a little bit.